# how can I use data posted from ajax in flask?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm having trouble getting data POSTed from jquery ajax.

```
$('#clickme').click( function() {
    var data = save_input(); // data

    data['_sid'] = $survey_id;  // survey_id injected from flask
    data['_uip'] = $user_ip; // user_ip injected from flask, request.remote_addr

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "{{ url_for('mod.load_ajax') }}",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });

    console.log(data);
});
```

from the code, `data` is a javascript object like

```
{
    'foo' : 'foo',
    'bar' : 'bar',
    'fo_' : 42,
}
```

what I'm trying to do in flask is :

```
@mod.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # load _sid and _uip from posted JSON and save other data
        # but request.form is empty.
        # >>> request.form
        # ImmutableMultiDict([]) 
        return str(request.form)
```

see, the ajax request is made but no data is submitted. I do `console.log(data)` with ajax so I can see that I really have some meaningful data in `data` variable in jquery. but request.form in ajax view is empty. Where is my data submitted?

Comment: Change `JSON.stringify(data)` to `data` and see what happens.

Comment: @Blender I do recieve the data. How can I receive this in JSON format?

Comment: Have you tried `request.json`?

Comment: @thkang use this as Data string: `"data=" + JSON.stringify(data);`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try

```
 $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "{{ url_for('mod.load_ajax') }}",
    data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Then from the server, you can refer to the variables in data like this :

```
request.json['foo']
```

Since the content type is specified as `application/json` the data is in `request.json`

Comment: Was pulling my hair out looking for this, request.json['foo'] did it for me. Thanks :)

Comment: `charset=UTF-8` was the trick. I was looking for it for hours.

Comment: yes, Flask request.data is empty when having no contentType in jquery ajax settings

Answer (score 13):

As per your example you are not sending a key value pair but rather assigning a JSON string to  the jQuery data option. As mentioned in the comments you have to stringify your JSON, create an object with a key (which will be used to access the JSON string from flask) and then assign it to the jQuery data key.

```
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "{{ url_for('mod.load_ajax') }}",
            data: {json_str: JSON.stringify(data)},
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });

    @mod.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def load_ajax():
        if request.method == "POST":
            # load _sid and _uip from posted JSON and save other data
            # but request.form is empty.
            # >>> request.form
            # ImmutableMultiDict([]) 
            return str(request.form['json_str']
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

On the flask side, use:

```
data = request.get_json()
```

The variable data now has the dictionary you sent using ajax and you can now manipulate it with python

Comment: Wrote that code after staying up for 24+ hours straight. Missed a few things. I take it back. It works perfectly. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried remove contentType? You suppose to post data to Flask.

could you try add fake data like

data:{"hello":"world"} inside ajax? just to check if the hello world arrive to request.form

Answer (score 0):

Get Data From Ajax (Flask)

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="inputbox" autocomplete="off">
```

Js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#inputbox").on("input",function(e){
            inputbox = $("#inputbox").val();
            console.log(inputbox)
            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "/path",
                data: {inputbox},
                success:function(res){


                }
            })
        });
    });
```

.py :

```
search_value = request.form.get("text")
```