# can flask use with jquery post?

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask

I am very new to Flask and before i proceed further, is it possible to perform a "post" from jquery to python function using flask and json? I'm not familiar with json too and therefore all those codes seem very complicated to me.

For [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_add_numbers')
```

how do I determine what to substitute `/_add_numbers`? I can't really find a good site to show me a simple tutorial or steps to do `post` with flask.

This is my current jQuery function:

```
$('#left_button').click(function(){
            $.post("cameraservo2.py", {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
                $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                alert("left button clicked");});

        });
```

Can I do this WITHOUT using the json??

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? `HTTP POST` is used to transmit data *to* the server. Are you trying to get data *from* the server and display it or are you trying to push data to the server for processing?

Comment: @msvalkon I am trying to post/transmit the data as well as to display the return data, as asked in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087507/how-to-execute-python-function-from-jquery-post/22087585?noredirect=1#22087585

Comment: @msvalkon i have just tried this example here https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample but failed. How do my html and javascript knows which python file i'm using? can't find it anywhere....

Comment: You assume that saying `$.post('cameraservo2.py')` runs the python code in `cameraservo2.py`. That does *absolutely* not happen.

Comment: Well that happened with cherrypy... in fact i saw it quite frequently on the web where AJAX is used. However, i am sure flask doesn't like it :( nor do i like flask.

Answer (score 4):

`$.post()` doesn't *use* JSON. It sends a regular POST request, with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type. In a Flask route this means that the fields you posted are found in the `request.form` object. If your view returns HTML you can insert it into your HTML document.

Just pick a route name that reflects what you want to do:

```
@app.route('/turn_servo', methods=['POST'])
def turn_servo_ajax():
    direction = request.form['direction']

    # do something with the direction value; it is a string
    if direction == 'left':
        # ...
    else:
        # ...

    return '<div>Turned the servo 50 degrees to the {}</div>'.format(direction)
```

You then use that route name in your `$.post`:

```
$('#left_button').click(function(){
            $.post("/turn_servo", {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
                $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                alert("left button clicked");});

        });
```

Comment: thanks! the "route" part is the confusing thing. How exactly do i know what to put at the place of `/turn_servo`? is it the function name in the jquery?

Comment: @yvonnezoe: No, it's the path portion of the request URL

Comment: `/turn_servo` is the URL which you're going to handle (i.e `http://yourdomain.com/turn_servo`). You will still have to call some function in your `cameraservo2.py` to actually turn the camera, but this is the way how you will get the direction from the user.

Comment: just to clarify, my python file must be in the same directory as my html file right? And this statement `@app.route('/turn_servo', methods=['POST'])` has to be unique? Actually I still couldn't understand why does the jquery knows which python script to post to. :(

Comment: No, Flask is not a CGI script. Flask either needs to be running as a separate server or needs to integrate with an exiting server. See the [deployment options documentation](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying/); there is a CGI option there but I'd *not* recommend using that. Instead, if you are new to Flask, I recommend you go through the tutorial in the documentation. Run a standalone development server and have it serve big your route and the HTML page. Don't try to fit into your existing webserver, not until you have the basics under your belt.

Comment: sorry, i'm confused here. Where do i put this `turn_servo_ajax():` function? in my existing python script or another separate python script?

Comment: @yvonnezoe: Do you have a Flask server running? Do you understand how a Python Flask server works? I have the strong impression that you think this works like a regular CGI script; it doesn't. Once you have a Flask server running (start with the development server as outlined in the documentation) you can add routes to that server in the same file, or by using separate Python modules and importing. *This requires a minimum understanding of Python modules and importing*.

Comment: yes i have done the routing part,just like the answer below. I run the Flask server `python routes.py` where routes.py contain the @app.route(). the server is running successfully but there still isn't any visible outcome. And I don't know which part goes wrong nor how to troubleshoot this problem. i have posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141570/accessing-flask-server-from-my-web-page?noredirect=1#comment33597615_22141570

Answer (score 1):

I've copied the code from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087507/how-to-execute-python-function-from-jquery-post#22087507) to demonstrate how the above answer (Martijns) works with your code.

```
# Save this file as app.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from cameraservo2 import your_cam_function

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/turn_servo', methods=['POST'])
def turn_servo_ajax():
    direction = request.form['direction']
    cam_result = your_cam_function(direction=direction)
    return '<div> {} </div>'.format(cam_result)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


# This code is in cameraservo2.py and is imported above.
# I've simplified it to a function (not a member of a class).
# You have to work out how to use it in your context.
def your_cam_function(**data):
    import pigpio
    import time

    servos=4
    key = data['direction']

    m=1500
    while (m >= 500 and m <= 2500):
        if (key =="left"):
            m=m+100
        elif (key =="right"):
            m=m-100

    pigpio.start()

    pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos, m) 
    servostatus= "Servo {} {} micro pulses".format(servos[0], key, m)
    print servostatus
    time.sleep(1)

    pigpio.stop()

    return servostatus
```

Now when you do a `POST` request to `/turn_servo` and give it a `direction: left`, it will call the function from your `cameraservo2.py`. The `turn_servo_ajax`-function will return a piece of HTML to the user, `<div>Servo x y micro pulses</div>`.

Comment: Thank you!! I will try it and let you know again :D thank you!! btw, does that mean i will have 2 python files?

Comment: where do I put `tun_servo_ajax` function? In cameraservo2.py or another python script?

Comment: @yvonnezone you put that in your flask application, whatever file manages your routing. It's typical for a flask application to have multiple files, please read through the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) to see how to proceed.

Comment: I'm more confused now. I have flask installed but im not sure if i'm using the flask server. I have my index files and other python files in var/www/. the quickstart isnt very helpful though. I cant find my flask files. Do i have to start/initiate it first?

Comment: Or do i have to run the python file, say routes.py, which contains the `turn_servo_ajax()` function first?

Comment: Then how? :( the quickstart clearly didn't mention where to put that function nor give me a complete example script. please help me. :( thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing the comment and pressed enter. I've updated my answer. Put the code above in their own files, run it and try to follow the quickstart. If you encounter further questions, please open up a new question on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help :) I copied those codes to a new file and run it in the terminal. I modified the last part to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` so that i can access it from another network computer. It says it is `running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 restarting with reloader`. But still nothing happen when i click the button. :( i think i will start a new question.