# Accessing Flask server from my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

This is a question continue from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088719/can-flask-use-with-jquery-post).

I am trying to control a servo motor using the image buttons on my web page. My servo controller is in the form of python script (cameraservo2.py) and I am using jQuery to `post` the data to the python function. The conclusion that I get from asking "how to run python script from webpage" is by using 'Flask' which is totally new to me. However I have installed it successfully using just `pip install Flask`. (let me know if i miss out anything?)

I have my `index.html, cameraservo3.py and routes.py` in my `/var/www`folder. My webserver is by default running and I can access it by my Raspberry Pi IP address from another network computer.

This is my `routes.py` code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from cameraservo3 import turnCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/turn_servo', methods=['POST'])
def turn_servo_ajax():
    direction = request.form['direction']
    cam_result = turnCamera(direction=direction)
    return '<div> {} </div>'.format(cam_result)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Part of my jQuery script in index.html:

```
$('#left_button').click(function(){
            $.post("/turn_servo", {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
                $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
                alert("left button clicked");});

        });
```

part of my html:

```
<div id="control_button">
    <img src="button_left.png" id="left_button" height="50" width="50">
    <img src="button_right.png" id="right_button" height="50" width="50">
    <p id="camerapos"> test </p>
  </div>
```

cameraservo2.py can be found in the answer for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088719/can-flask-use-with-jquery-post) there. I run `python routes.py` and it gave me

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

But the script (cameraservo2.py) doesn't get executed when I click the left_button. What's wrong? Which part have I done wrong??

The quickstart guide of Flask isn't very helpful as well. :/

Comment: replace the `your_cam_function` with `turnCamera`. `turnCamera` is supposed to be the function to call.

Comment: Is there actually an element in your DOM with an ID of `left_button`?  Does it appear before or *after* this script in the DOM?  Is there an element with the ID of `camerapos` in the DOM?  Seeing the key bits of your `index.html` template would help :-)

Comment: @msvalkon sorry bout the mistake. yes, i did use `turnCamera` in my code but still nothing happens. i suspect my problem may be about the :5000 port... but how can i troubleshoot where is problem?

Comment: You'll need to load the `index.html` page from the flask server as well; you can make it a static page or a new route at `/` that returns the script. Otherwise you run into a [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) violation; a page at `http://localhost/` isn't allowed to use AJAX to post to `http://localhost:5000` (different port numbers).

Comment: @SeanVieira yes i do. updated my question as above. :) and it is after the script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahh, that makes sense! so you mean, i should do another @app.route() for index.html too right?

Comment: @yvonnezoe: exactly; it can use a template to render that page; that'd allow you to use the `url_for()` function to let Flask fill in the target URL for the `$.post()` call, for example.

Comment: hmm totally new to Flask here, so those terms are still confusing. but will do more research based on the direction you gave me. thank you! :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters umm wait, just a quick question here. is it similar to cherrypy?? in this case, i have a camera app running on the server (not sure what it is running on, the developer hasnt reply me) and i have no idea how to let it run on cherrypy server. so if flask is the same as cherrypy, it can't solve my problem. oh no. :(

Comment: @yvonnezoe: CherryPy is another Python web server, so yes, Flask and CherryPy are similar. Flask is a little newer, a little easier to work with (in my experience). But you should be able to get CherryPy to do the same thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll run into the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions unless you serve the `index.html` file from the same host and port number. It's easiest to just add the `index.html` page to your Flask server too.

Add a `/` route that serves the page that will do the AJAX post. You could use a template to fill in the route here for `$.post()` to. If using Jinja2 for the template, that would be:

```
@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and the file `index.html` in the `templates` subdirectory of your Flask project with:

```js
$('#left_button').click(function(){
        $.post("{{ url_for('turn_servo_ajax') }}", {direction:"left"}).done(function (reply) {
            $('#camerapos').empty().append(reply);
            alert("left button clicked");});

    });
```

where the `{{ }}` part is Jinja2 template syntax, and [`url_for()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.url_for) returns a fully-formed URL for the `turn_servo_ajax` view function.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new folder called `templates` in /var/www directory and put all necessary files, i.e. index.html, jquery js and css file and images, into the folder. But my formatting is all gone. now i can't even click on the button...

Comment: @yvonnezoe: that usually means the links in the `<style>` tags are now incorrect and your CSS is not loading.

Comment: but it shouldn't be. because i put all of them in the same directory as index.html and it was working fine in the /var/www... :(

Comment: @yvonnezoe: ah, right, but templates need to be loaded explicitly. But static information in the `static` folder and adjust the urls to load `static/filename.css` instead.

Comment: ahhhh i was so hopeful that that's the only problem but nothing happens after i clicked on the img again. I looked at the terminal and it returns me quite some errors... i pasted them here: http://pastebin.com/eGgVQnML do i have to put jsonify or anything else at anywhere?

Comment: @yvonnezoe: That's 3 times the same error; the Flask code is working but apparently the `cameraservo3.turnCamera()` does something wrong.

Comment: Hmm that's true. but this section of code should give `m` a number.. `m=1500
    while (m >= 500 and m <= 2500):
        if (key =="left"):
            m=m+100
        elif (key =="right"):
            m=m-100` 
Anyway, I am sure this code won't work practically because it will initialize `m=1500` everytime i click it, which is unwanted.  but i will settle that later.

Comment: it's working? :D yayy! so now i'm moving to next phase of troubleshooting! thank you so much for your guidance and help!

Comment: Well, the bottom line is that your *Flask* code works. :-) The POST arrives, the view does what it is supposed to do.