# AJAX not resolving url correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have an HTML form that I want to submit to a flask endpoint, /add_int. When the form is submitted I intercept it with Jquery and submit the form to the endpoint using AJAX as follows:

```
var form = $( this ).serialize()

$.post({                           
   url: "{{ url_for('add_int') }}",
   data: JSON.stringify(form),
   contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',       
   success: function(resp) {
       console.log(resp);
   }
 });
```

The endpoint looks like this:

```
 @app.route('/add_int', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 @login_required
 def add_int():
    # do stuff
    return jsonify(status="success!")
```

My issue is that **I never get to the endpoint**.

When I examine my console I see

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/[object%20Object] 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

instead of

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_int
```

as I'd expect.

Note that if I set

```
url: '/add_int',
```

I run into the same problem.

I've found cases that use almost identical code that don't mention this problem:
e.g. [how can I use data posted from ajax in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908864/how-can-i-use-data-posted-from-ajax-in-flask)

My guess, is that my url is being resolved as a String object rather than a url, but I can't figure out why it's happening, and how to fix it.

**What's going on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not specifying the hash keys explicitly. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post("{{ url_for('add_int') }}",
        JSON.stringify(form),
        function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        },
       'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
       );
```

Comment: To add to the answer a little, `$.ajax` needs the `url` key. The shortcuts (.e.g, `$.get`, `$.post`) take the URL as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the call to `JSON.stringify`, you can pass a serialized form directly as `POST` data and JSON.stringify is turning your object into `[Object object]`.

`url: '/add_int',` isn't working because (it appears that) your frontend is running on a different port than the backend, so it will be rejected as a "cross domain" request. Have you inspected the value that `"{{ url_for('add_int') }}"` is returning?

Comment: I made the change to JSON.stringify, to no avail.

Comment: I just updated my answer, what is `"{{ url_for('add_int') }}"` returning? And if you inspect the request in the console, is the correct data now being passed to the server?

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about the url because I can use url: '/add_int' as a url for a GET ajax request without any difficulties

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it looks like `url_for` is failing and returning an error or something instead of the url you are expecting. My advice would be to dump the return value and see what's going on.